# Can't get value using map in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, hashmap

I have a problem while dealing with the `Map` data structure in JavaScript/TypeScript. Here is the code:

```js
curUsername: string = 'qweqwe';  
avatars: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

this.userService.getAllFriends(this.curUsername).then(data => {
    if (data.success === true) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
            this.avatars.set(data.users[i].username, data.users[i].avatar);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Error when getting friends from database: ",data.message);
    }
});
```

There is no problem with the backend, however when I console log in the browser, it says that the `map` is empty. But the map does have entries, like the image shown below:

[image]

And I can't get the value using key.

Comment: What kind of type is data.users (array, object, map) ?

Comment: It is Array<Object>

Comment: I've asked because I thought that it could be undefined and so the loop was never executed, I would suggest you to see if the loop is executed anyway...

Comment: I kind of know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I'm new to javascript. I think the problem is that the callback is async. When I console log outside the "this.userService.getAllFriends().then()". There is no value in the map. What do you think about this. Thanks!!

Comment: That **.then** is a function of some library or is a Promise?  Even if it was a Promise polyfill it would throw an exception when rejected. If it is a Promise, is possible that is still pending... but I still think that is just the loop, put a _console.log_ with some message inside  the _if_ clause as you done for the _else_ ...